# How to Query Subtopics in Experience Cloud?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, community-cloud, topics

I have a LWC which should show dynamic name of the subtopics in the form of Accordion Section.

How can I query subtopics under the hood? They are eventually 'Topics' but I've a feeling that it resides under different object.

Can we retrieve it using following JS query?

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

But I really don't know how to proceed from here as it does not resides under [Topic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_topic.htm) object? Can anyone help to query the subtopics name?

[image]